# SQLAlchemy async engine with ORM unable to get database tables

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, sqlalchemy, orm

I have switched my SQLAlchemy database code to use an async engine and I am having trouble establishing basic functionality.

I have a class that starts the database like this:

```
class PostgresDb:

    def __init__(self):
        self._session = None
        self._engine = None

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._session, name)

    def init(self):
        self._engine = create_async_engine(
            ENGINE,
            echo=True,
            future=True)

        self._session = sessionmaker(
            self._engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession
        )()

   async def create_all(self):
        async with self._engine.begin() as conn:
            await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)

   # Other methods...
```

Example of how create_all gets called:

```
async def init_db_tables():
    self.init()
    await self.create_all()
asyncio.run(init_db_tables())
```

When I want to achieve basic functionality, like getting all the tables, I can do something like:

```
def get_tables(self):
    with create_engine(SYNCHRONOUS_ENGINE).connect() as conn:
        meta = MetaData(conn, schema=SCHEMA)
        meta.reflect(views=True)
        table_list = meta.tables
        return table_list
```

This is not ideal as I need to actually pass in a synchronous engine connection instead of the actual async engine I am using in the Class. It is also very verbose and shouldn't need to be initiated like this for every query.

I have tried doing something like this to select the table 'appuser' from the database:

```
async def get_tables(self):
    self.init()
    async with self._session() as session:
        q = select('appuser')
        result = await session.execute(q)
        curr = result.scalars()
        for i in curr:
            print(i)
```

Which I've tried calling like this

```
db = PostgresDb()
asyncio.run(db.get_tables())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(db.get_tables())
```

These both give error:

```
async with self._session() as session:
TypeError: 'AsyncSession' object is not callable
```

Calling it with `db.get_tables()` errors `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'PostgresDb.get_tables' was never awaited db.get_tables() RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`

Trying to use `inspector` with `run_sync` like this:

```
    async def get_tables(self):
        await self.init()
        async with self._engine.begin() as conn:
            inspector = conn.run_sync(inspect(conn))
            table_names = await conn.run_sync(inspector.get_table_names())
            print(table_names)
```

Returns error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoInspectionAvailable: Inspection on an AsyncConnection is currently not supported. Please use ``run_sync`` to pass a callable where it's possible to call ``inspect`` on the passed connection.
```

I have read the documentation at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio.AsyncConnection.run_sync but I am still unclear about how to work cleanly with async engines.

How can I execute a simple query `get all tables` in SQLAlchemy using the async engine?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the tables by running reflecting the metadata inside a connection's `run_sync` method:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

...

    async def get_tables(self):
        self.init()
        async with self._engine.connect() as conn:
            # We could just use Base.metadata, but perhaps
            # the database contains other tables as well as those
            # defined in Base's metadata.
            metadata = sa.MetaData(schema='public')
            await conn.run_sync(metadata.reflect)
        return metadata.tables
```

To query a single table, given only the table name, we can wrap the name in a table object, and pass it and `'*'` to `select` (or pass `sa.text(select * from appusers)`).

```py
    async def read_table(self):
        self.init()
        async with self._session() as session:
            q = sa.select(sa.table('appusers'), sa.text('*'))
            result = await session.execute(q)
            rows = result.scalars()
            for i in rows:
                print(i)
```

The error

> 'AsyncSession' object is not callable

is raised because `orm.sessionmaker(...)()` already returns a `Session` instance, so there is no need to call it. Depending on whether you want your class to use a single session throughout its lifetime, or a new session each time a method is called, you can either not call the session when you use it:

```py
async with self._session as session:
    ...
```

or not call the result of calling `sessionmaker` immediately:

```py
self._session = orm.sessionmaker(...)

async with self._session() as session:
    ...
```

It's worth noting that for simple applications, only one each of `engine` and `sessionmaker` are required, so there isn't much benefit in recreating them in the `init` method before each method call.  Create them once and pass them to `__init__`.

```py
engine = create_async_engine(...)
Session = orm.sessionmaker(...)

class Postgresdb:

    def __init__(self, engine, session_class):
        self._engine = engine
        self._session = session_class
```